# How can I display data on a Google Maps without the Lat and Long?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to display some information to my users. But I want the data is country and state specific. Now is there a way to display data to a state and country without having to provide the LAT and LONG?

I want to highlight the state and once the use click on it display some information.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API v3 uses geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) for location information on the map.  To position state and or country polygons on the map you will need data for them (which will need to include their geographic coordinates). There are publicly available polygons, the Natural Earth data set being one that is available in FusionTables.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary)

or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076651/color-in-country)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I downloaded the US State tables, but when I try to add the KML data nothing happens... Do I need to use the embeedable code or I can use my own?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help, what did you do? What errors do you get?

Comment: One other question.. is there a place where I can find the KML for all countries and states? I saw on google that they have the US states but would it be possible to get all the world countries and states?

Comment: The [Natural Earth data set](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html) includes that (referenced in one of the questions I linked to.